# Installing Creative NX Webcam

Tags: webcam

I want to install my Creative NX webcam on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The installation CD is for Windows. Support for this product doesn't exist anymore on Creative site. How to install it on Ubuntu?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: doesn't it work out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That webcam from what I have read should work out of the box. In Ubuntu there is no need to install additional drivers (That's for Windows). Just plug it in and it should work.

If you want to test it out, open **Software Center** and install **cheese** which is a GUI app for webcams.

I should also add that it appears in the already confirmed supported webcams here (Since 2008): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsMultimediaWebCamerasCreative

It had a couple of problems in 2006 but they were fixed around 2007.

It also appears in the GSPCA Devices compatibility list (And this list is from 2009): http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Gspca_devices

And even the older version of the list: http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca5xx.html

So what I am trying to say is:

1. Almost all hardware will work out of the box in Ubuntu. Just literally plug it in and.. done.
2. Driver installation is for less than 1% of hardware (Proprietary stuff like Nvidia, Ati, Broadcom) but for each new version of Ubuntu you will see an increased amount of new hardware supported.

Dont' be amazed if everything in your PC and anything you connect to it just works when you connect it.

Comment: Hi Luis, your last answer was very helpful. Thanks for that. This time, its bit more complicated. I've recently moved to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, trying to get a clean image with the same Creative Webcam NX, tested with Cheese as you mentioned above. But don't get any image. Cheese shows from time to time a dizzy image but remains black most of the time. Do you think I can still use this webcam? How?

Comment: @kamyogi - Thanks buddy. About the issues you are mentioning with Cheese, this are bugs with Cheese. If you install another program, for example guvcview, kamorama, kamerka they will surely work better than cheese. At least until the bugs related to cheese are fixed. For my part I recommend guvcview which solved many problems. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. A little breakthrough though. I reinstalled Cheese and tested my webcam. After a still image for some time, it gives good result. Now it captures my movements and works good. It assures me that my webcam is functional. All this for a video chat in my Gmail with someone who's on Windows at the other end. I've installed google-talkplugin_current_i386.deb (I am on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS), checked Chat settings but the there's no image in the box. My status shows I have a camera and also 'gspca main driver' show up in the Camera settings!

Comment: If you like we can talk in chat since I happen to be following this type of problems.

Comment: How to chat mate? Should I leave my instant messaging ID here? :)